# Minimizing the potential energy in a hyperelasticity problem

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, functional-derivatives

I am currently using the FEniCS/DOLFINx package to simulate deformations on a mesh volume.
Following [this tutorial](https://jsdokken.com/dolfinx-tutorial/chapter2/hyperelasticity.html), I am using the following equation to find $u$ such as $L(u)=0$:
$$L = \vec{\nabla} \vec{v} \cdot P ~\vec{dx} - \vec{T} \cdot \vec{v} ~\vec{ds}$$ (I may have forgotten integrals here)
with

- $P$ the first Piola Kirchhoff stress $P = \dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial F}$ with $F$ the deformation gradient.
- $\vec{dx}$ and $\vec{ds}$ the volume and surface element
- $\vec{T}$ a traction force applied on the surface.

Originally, the goal would be to minimize the potential energy, which writes itself as:

$$\Pi = \int_{\Omega} \psi (u) \,dx - \int_{\partial \Omega} T\cdot u \,ds$$

with $\psi$ the energy density function.

My question is: **what is the link between these two equations ? How to get to the first one starting from the second one ?** I know that the [Gateaux derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative) is used in that case but I don't know how to apply it to $\Pi$.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE. I don't see two equations, what is your first one? Also, what $F$, $\psi$, and $v$ stand for? I'm guessing that the first two are the deformation gradient and energy density function, but I am not sure, though.

Comment: Also, I think that maybe [Computational Science Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) might be better suited for this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @nicoguaro. I edited the post, $L$ is the first equation, and $u$ and $v$ correspond to the displacement functions that will be the solution of the equation (a displacement field).

Comment: Well, I don't understand your first equation. Where did you get it from?

Comment: It is from the [linked tutorial](https://jsdokken.com/dolfinx-tutorial/chapter2/hyperelasticity.html). It should correspond to the variational form written on residual from. My concern was how to get it, as it seems to be obtained from the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on [the FEniCS forum from @kamensky](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/minimizing-the-potential-energy-in-a-hyperelasticity-problem/10175), so I will paste the answer given here to close the subject:

If you’ve studied calculus of variations before, it may help to use the
notation $\partial u$ for the test function instead of $v$, then think
about the Gateaux derivative of $\Pi$ with respect to $u$ in the direction
$\delta u$ to zero (by analogy to seeking the minimum of a univariate
function by looking for an argument such that its ordinary derivative is
zero):

$$d\Pi(\boldsymbol{u} ; \delta\boldsymbol{u}) = \delta \Pi = \int_\Omega 
 \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial F} : \delta \boldsymbol F d \Omega - 
 \int_{\partial\Omega} T \cdot \delta \boldsymbol u d \partial\Omega = 0,$$

where the variation $\delta \boldsymbol F$ is also a Gateaux derivative
with respect to the displacement of $\boldsymbol F = \nabla \boldsymbol u + 
 \boldsymbol I$, i.e.

$$\delta \boldsymbol F = d\boldsymbol{F}(\boldsymbol u\,; 
 \delta\boldsymbol{u}) = \nabla (\delta \boldsymbol u).$$

Making the substitutions

$$\partial \psi / \partial \boldsymbol F \rightarrow \boldsymbol P, \delta 
 \boldsymbol F \rightarrow \nabla (\delta \boldsymbol u), \delta \boldsymbol 
 u \rightarrow \boldsymbol v,$$

You recover the weak form

$$\int_\Omega \nabla \boldsymbol v : \boldsymbol P ~d\Omega - \int_{\partial 
 \Omega} \boldsymbol T \cdot \boldsymbol v ~d\partial\Omega
 = 0 ~~\forall v.$$